# Jasperstarter: Unable to load driver

Tags: jdbc, jasper-reports, jasperstarter

I am using JasperStarter 3.0.0 in Linux as follows:

`sudo /home/name/jasperstarter/bin/jasperstarter pr Prueba_1.jrxml -f pdf -t generic --db-url jdbc:sqlite:/home/name/DATA/basename.sqlite --db-driver /home/name/jasperstarter/jdbc/sqlitejdbc-v056.jar`

I am running it from the folder where I have my report (Prueba_1.jrxml), but I get the error message:

> Unable to load driver: /home/name/jasperstarter/jdbc/sqlitejdbc-v056.jar

What I see in all posts is that I must have my drivers in the jdbc file, and I have it.

I check the path of the driver and it is well written.

Time ago this same command was working (with the same files etc.), but not now. The only thing I changed was the definition of the Path of Java in etc/profile, because it was wrong.

Now when typing echo $JAVA_HOME and echo $PATH it is everything OK: they are pointing to the last Java folder (jre1.8.0.101)

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is *jasperstarter*?

Comment: JasperStarter is a command line program to run reports in Jasper (http://jasperstarter.cenote.de/)

Comment: Maybe it is better to send this question to the author of this tool (on site)

Comment: It looks like the parameter of `--db-driver` should be the **class name of the driver**, not the path of the jar file. This is also shown in the example on that site you link to.

Answer (score 0):

Effectively, it was matter of writting the class name of the driver, not the path.

I did it and the error dissapeared

Thank you very much for your asnwers!!